How to mock object used inside a method?
I have method
    private void performAgentAction(UUID id, ActionType actionType) {
        StartOrStopAgentActionContext startOrStopAgentActionContext = new StartOrStopAgentActionContext();
        accessManager.applyRegisteredConstraints(startOrStopAgentActionContext);
        if(!startOrStopAgentActionContext.isPermitted()) {
            throw new AccessDeniedException(Agent.class.getName(), messages.getMessage(
                    "msg://ru.ctsg.damdbf.manager.core.service.impl/AgentServiceImpl.accessDenied"));
        }

        Agent agent = agentRepository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException(messages.getMessage(AGENT_NOT_FOUND)));

        AgentActionDto dto = agentMapper.toAgentActionDto(agent);
        dto.setAction(actionType.getId());

        if (actionType == ActionType.START) {
            agentHandler.executeAction(dto);
            agent.setStatus(AgentStatus.STARTING);
            agent.setLastStartDate(new Date());
        } else {
            agentHandler.executeAction(dto);
            agent.setStatus(AgentStatus.STOPPING);
        }
        agentRepository.save(agent);
    }

I need to test for throwing an AccessDeniedException. How can I change the StartOrStopAgentActionContext object creation behavior? I need startOrStopAgentActionContext.isPermitted() to return false. Now it always returns true.

Inject a factory. Use a different factory in your test which returns a context that returns false. You don't need Mockito for that, plain Java will do.
